# How to Implement Unit test on my retrofit2 presenter using mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, retrofit2

i want to make a unit testing by using mockito dependencies on my code. it is always failed because view.processMatchData(data) and view.hideLoading() are in closure part in this presenter code, so that unit test will not detect them. Please, somebody help me solve this problem.

```
open class MatchSearchPresenter(
    private val view: MatchSearchView,
    private val apiService: ApiService,
    private val cari : String
) {
    fun searchMatch() {
        view.showLoading()
        apiService.loadSearchMatch(cari).enqueue(object : Callback<MatchSearchResponseModel> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<MatchSearchResponseModel>, response: Response<MatchSearchResponseModel>)
                {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val data = response.body()!!
                        view.processMatchData(data)
                    }
                    view.hideLoading()
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<MatchSearchResponseModel>, error: Throwable)
                {
                    Log.e("Error", error.message)
                    view.hideLoading()
                }
        })
    }
}
```

here are my unit test :

```
class MatchSearchPresenterTest {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var view: MatchSearchView
    @Mock
    private lateinit var apiService: ApiService
    @Mock
    private lateinit var teamPresenter: MatchSearchPresenter
    @Mock
    private lateinit var call: Call<MatchSearchResponseModel>
    @Mock
    private lateinit var something: Callback<MatchSearchResponseModel>


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        val kata = "Man United"
        teamPresenter = MatchSearchPresenter(view, apiService, kata )
    }
    @Test
    fun searchMatch() {
        val teamId = "Man United"
        val teams: MutableList<PrevMatchData> = mutableListOf()
        val data = MatchSearchResponseModel(teams)

        teamPresenter.searchMatch()

        argumentCaptor<MatchSearchView>().apply {
            Mockito.verify(apiService.loadSearchMatch(teamId).enqueue(something))
            firstValue.processMatchData(data)
            firstValue.hideLoading()
        }

        Mockito.verify(view).showLoading()
        Mockito.verify(view).processMatchData(data)
        Mockito.verify(view).hideLoading()
    }
}
```

but this is not working by showing message like this :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.footballleaguecataloguefourth.ui_bottom_navigation.schedule.match_search.MatchSearchPresenter.searchMatch(MatchSearchPresenter.kt:19)
    at com.example.footballleaguecataloguefourth.ui_bottom_navigation.schedule.match_search.MatchSearchPresenterTest.searchMatch(MatchSearchPresenterTest.kt:41)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want here is to have the call returned by `ApiService` call the correct method as soon as it's enqueued.

To do this you can use Mockito's `thenAnswer` - [Here's](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) an example. In your case, you can try this:

```
Mockito.`when`(call.enqueue(Mockito.any())).thenAnswer {
    (it.getArgument(0) as Callback<MatchSearchResponseModel>).onResponse(
        call,
        Response.success(MatchSearchResponseModel(/*whatever is needed to build this object*/))
    )
}
```

Here, you make sure that once `call.enqueue` is called with any argument, it'll immediately call the `onResponse` method with a success reponse. You can do something similar for an error and you can also call `onFailure`.

The last thing you need to do is to make sure that your api service returns the configured mocked `call`:

```
 Mockito.`when`(apiService.loadSearchMatch(kata)).thenReturn(call)
```

I'd put this per test. So before you call your presenter method, I'd configure the mocks like this.

Now, calling `teamPresenter.searchMatch()`, should call `apiService.loadSearchMatch(cari)`, which will return the mocked call that once enqueued will call the passed callback's `onResponse` method.

Lastly, as you might have noticed `when` is actually written with backticks. This is because it's a kotlin keyword that needs to be escaped. Not only for this reason but many more, you could consider using [Mockito Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) which is a superb kotlin library wrapping mockito and makes life much easier.